# Learning SQL in CS50: RuntimeError: near "IF": syntax error

Tags: mysql, cs50

I'm trying to create a table called stock that keeps track of how much stock someone has after buying a certain amount. This is the most complex SQL code I've tried so far, and I think I'm writing something wrong. Can someone spot the error(s)?

```
db.execute("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM stock WHERE symbol = :symbol AND userid = :userid) 
    UPDATE stock SET (amount = amount + 1) WHERE userid = :userid 
    ELSE INSERT INTO stock (userid, symbol, amount) 
    VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = :userid), 
        :symbol, :amount", userid = session["user_id"], symbol = symbol, amount = share_number)
```

Comment: IF()  in mysql  is a function `IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)` and   a not  statement IF

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you add the tag for your particular DBMS (mysql, sqlserver, oracle, ..) as some sql features are very specific? Also, it that cs50 tag correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket after

```
INSERT INTO stock (userid, symbol, amount) 
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = :userid), :symbol, :amount
```

and instead of 
`(SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = :userid)` you could simply write

```
INSERT INTO stock (userid, symbol, amount) 
VALUES (:userid, :symbol, :amount)
```